# .htaccess redirect domain without language subfolder to language subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I had got a domain like this "domain.com", now I create subfolders for languages.
Now my domain has this subfolders "domain.it/it/" and "domain.com/en/".
I need to redirect only the root domain "domain.it" to "domain.com/it/, I tried to do this in my .htaccess but it goes in "Too many redirect":

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://www.domain.it/it/ [R=301,L]
```

And this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(en|it)/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.domain.it/it/ [L,R=301]
```

How can I do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first rule + condition always match so cause an infinite loop. You only need one rule for this situation:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!(?:it|en)/).* https://www.domain.it/it/$0 [L,R=301]
```

This uses a negative look-ahead assertion with non-capturing sub-pattern. However, I'd advise you also add another rule (*before* that one) to aid manually entered/poorly copied URLs:

```
RewriteRule ^(?:it|en)$ https://www.domain.it/$0/ [L,R=301]
```